Microsoft Bot Framework Python SDK ErrorResponseException: Operation returned an invalid status code 'Unauthorized'
So basically, I'm experiencing the same behaviour as displayed here, but for Sample 18: Bot-Authentication: other question
The accepted solution in that thread is not viable for me. I need to have european data residency.
I have followed this documentation step-by-step (except for the azure part which I do not have permission for, but my colleague did this part). It is not documented in the python documentation, but I have also added some variables to my .env, which i found here in the microsoft docs so it looks like this:
MicrosoftAppId = "YYY"
MicrosoftAppPassword = "YYY"
MicrosoftAppType = "MultiTenant"
MicrosoftAppTenantId = "YYY"
ConnectionName = "YYY"

BotOpenIdMetadata = "https://login.botframework.com/v1/.well-known/openidconfiguration"
CallerId = "urn:botframework:azure"
OAuthUrl = "https://europe.token.botframework.com/"
ToBotFromChannelOpenIdMetadataUrl = "https://login.botframework.com/v1/.well-known/openidconfiguration"
ToBotFromChannelTokenIssuer = "https://api.botframework.com"
ToBotFromEmulatorOpenIdMetadataUrl = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/botframework.com/v2.0/.well-known/openid-configuration"
ToChannelFromBotLoginUrl = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/{0}"
ToChannelFromBotOAuthScope = "https://api.botframework.com"
ValidateAuthority = true

Nothing helped and I cant find any further information. I have "Bypass ngrok for local addresses" enabled in the emulator and am using my own userId, so that cant be the reason either.

this is really an Authentication question as opposed to a Python coding question. So better remove the python tag.

As far as I understand, Python is no longer supported on the BotFramework side and I am not sure if there is any ongoing support. However, you can still use C# or NodeJs.

Haven't found anything about python no longer being supported @RajeeshMenoth, the documentation says:
"The Bot Framework JavaScript, C#, and Python SDKs will continue to be supported, however, the Java SDK is being retired with final long-term support ending in November 2023."

As per the earlier communication, The Bot Framework Python SDK is being retired with final long-term support ending in November 2023. Look like document is modified but still you can check this release comment https://github.com/microsoft/botbuilder-python/releases/tag/4.14.3

Well it would be nice to have that in the documentation which I cited. But thats on microsoft, thanks though, I guess it's not really worth it fixing this in python if it is retired anyways.
